# EditText onFocusChanged listener for listView array adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I am having an issue with `EditText` losing focus when I do `notifyDataChanged()` in a `ListView` array adapter. So, based on the research, some say that `onFocusChanged()` listener can be used to tackle this problem. Can anybody give me a code example?

Seems like you need to check if the focus is lost on the current edid Text and use a variable to keep track and get the focus back.

I have tried the `XML` way it did not help, so not that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your example:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
             if(!hasFocus)
               v.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, add these attributes to your `EditText`, if you already haven't:

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Also, you might need to add `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` to your listview.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried this before and it does not work. When i request the focus, i get the focus on the edidtext, but i can't type anything on the keyboard. Also my edittext only takes in numbers, so the keyboard does not change to the number one. it's just stuck with ASIC keyboard. I can move the cursor around, but no change.

Comment: Are you using inputType in your EditText?

Comment: yeah    android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Comment: Remove this line and you'll see the usual keyboard.

Comment: No, removing the inputType did not help. I also added the other attributes you stated, but does not help. So just to reiterate what happen, when i click on the edidtext, i get focus; i see the cursor and i can move that around. But can't modify anything; there is a softkeyboard. Pressing the delete key on the softkeyboard won't delete anything or can't add anything. Also i need the number keyboard. This is for a listView array adapter.

Comment: Try adding windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the manifest listview.setItemsCanFocus(true) for the listview. Change inputtype to text if you want to enter something other than numbers.

Comment: Does not help. Now, when I select the edidText in the listView, it moves my contents up. Then, same behaviour as before, where the cursor can be moved in the edidText, the soft ASIC keyboard appears and I can't type anything. It seems like the focus is locked onto the edidText. No way to move it.